# How to use Mail App to send Email, On Edit

Tags: google-apps-script

My company is beginning to use a Google Form for customers to submit order requests with. There is a portion that uses Data Validation for us to confirm when the order is (or is not) placed.

I'm looking to use a script to send an email when "Column H" is edited to say "Yes", to the email address provided on that row, confirming the order.

Additionally, is there a way to send one message when Column H says "Yes" and a different message when it says "No"?

If possible, I would like to be able to pull the email address from the edited row, as well as the item request information (columns E,F,G). Is this possible?

I'm completely new to using these scripts so I am unfamiliar with the MailApp function.

Comment: Yes, of course context and information can be used to run different code sections. There are a LOT of questions that use `MailApp` in a function triggered on edit. Almost all of them have some additional condition that is applied to control the specific desired email behavior. The Apps Script API reference (easily googled and directly linked from the Script Editor's help menu), and the autocomplete functionality in the editor will be invaluable as you teach yourself the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem. You can do all of that relatively easily.

I highly recommend that you follow the [Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) tutorial in order to first learn how to select the specific values that you want (those in columns E,F,G) and use them in a template email.

Then look at how to implement triggers. There is some basic information provided [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), but if you're not very familiar with reading through developer documentation, it can be a little challenging to fully understand. So take this code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" && range.getA1Notation() === "A1") {
    Browser.msgBox("You edited cell A1!");
  }
}
```

and run it in Google Apps Script. (You may first have to manually run the code by clicking the "Play" button and accept the warnings/permissions.)

[image]

Change the value in Sheet1!A1 and you'll see a popup appear saying that you edited the cell. You can build off that code, some [Trigger documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), and the mail merge tutorial to build out everything you want.